# Is Captain Haddock Scottish?

Tags: character, adventures-of-tintin

I just saw `The Adventures of Tintin` and I could see that Captain Haddock's character has a very thick Scottish accent. I don't recollect any reference made in the original series by Hergé about Captain Haddock's Scottish heritage. Is there a particular reason for this?

PS: I had to tag this question as something, since `accents`/`tintin` weren't in the existing tag list

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appears to be a stylistic decision on the part of Andy Serkis and Steven Spielberg, and is in keeping with Hollywood's fascination for Scottish accents (see the Vikings in *How to Train Your Dragon*, *Shrek*, the lack of a Welsh Smurf).

Naturally, fans are up in arms about this, especially those who think he should have an English accent (specifically Cornish), but this is also wrong as Herge wrote him as a Belgian, like his young friend, Tintin. Haddock is thought to be descended from the Chevalier François de Hadoque , a French sea captain.

Comment: So basically, from the original story, he belongs to no particular country, so he might as well be portrayed as a person from a country that Hollywood thinks is appropriate for traits such as that of Captain Haddock's? Interesting observation. +1

Comment: And now add *Brave* to that list ;)